# Output of my high lockTime and high page_faults value also

Tags: mongodb

we are using mongodb for our collections .

This is my stats of my development server .

My concerns are  that there is high `lockTime` on my development server and also there are high `page_faults` value also .

Please tell me how can we resolve this ??

```
PRIMARY>   db.serverStatus()
{
        "host" : "ubsc-aio:27018",
        "version" : "2.0.4",
        "process" : "mongod",
        "uptime" : 3278692,
        "uptimeEstimate" : 3098346,
        "localTime" : ISODate("2013-08-30T10:55:06.997Z"),
        "globalLock" : {
                "totalTime" : 3278692551767,
                "lockTime" : 139516930214,
                "ratio" : 0.0425526114483682,
                "currentQueue" : {
                        "total" : 0,
                        "readers" : 0,
                        "writers" : 0
                },
                "activeClients" : {
                        "total" : 1,
                        "readers" : 1,
                        "writers" : 0
                }
        },
        "mem" : {
                "bits" : 64,
                "resident" : 2009,
                "virtual" : 23455,
                "supported" : true,
                "mapped" : 11420,
                "mappedWithJournal" : 22840
        },
        "connections" : {
                "current" : 162,
                "available" : 7838
        },
        "extra_info" : {
                "note" : "fields vary by platform",
                "heap_usage_bytes" : 3645040,
                "page_faults" : 4147570
        },
        "indexCounters" : {
                "btree" : {
                        "accesses" : 902898,
                        "hits" : 901095,
                        "misses" : 1803,
                        "resets" : 0,
                        "missRatio" : 0.0019969033046922245
                }
        },
        "backgroundFlushing" : {
                "flushes" : 54639,
                "total_ms" : 36709498,
                "average_ms" : 671.8552316111203,
                "last_ms" : 81,
                "last_finished" : ISODate("2013-08-30T10:54:43.013Z")
        },
        "cursors" : {
                "totalOpen" : 1,
                "clientCursors_size" : 1,
                "timedOut" : 7
        },
        "network" : {
                "bytesIn" : 77779294441,
                "bytesOut" : 314231714161,
                "numRequests" : 189861092
        },
        "repl" : {
                "setName" : "at",
                "ismaster" : true,
                "secondary" : false,
                "hosts" : [
                        "localhost:27018",
                        "localhost:27017"
                ],
                "arbiters" : [
                        "localhost:27019"
                ],
                "primary" : "localhost:27018",
                "me" : "localhost:27018"
        },
        "opcounters" : {
                "insert" : 303294,
                "query" : 133717078,
                "update" : 59123588,
                "delete" : 234256,
                "getmore" : 48037783,
                "command" : 125805489
        },
        "asserts" : {
                "regular" : 0,
                "warning" : 0,
                "msg" : 0,
                "user" : 16576,
                "rollovers" : 0
        },
        "writeBacksQueued" : false,
        "dur" : {
                "commits" : 28,
                "journaledMB" : 0.08192,
                "writeToDataFilesMB" : 0.116123,
                "compression" : 0.6743163821345669,
                "commitsInWriteLock" : 0,
                "earlyCommits" : 0,
                "timeMs" : {
                        "dt" : 3000,
                        "prepLogBuffer" : 0,
                        "writeToJournal" : 25,
                        "writeToDataFiles" : 2,
                        "remapPrivateView" : 1
                }
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Using `serverStatus()` we can't say page-faults value to be high or low, as this counter is always increasing in it. Better use `mongostat` to check current page-faults.

Comment: Use MMS https://mms.mongodb.com/ and watch this presentation : http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/webinar-performance-tuning-and-monitoring-using-mms, to get ideas about what to look for to have resolution fro your problem. (if it is a problem really). Just number of pagefaults does not tell too much